# Como criar componentes dinâmicos em React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

Preciso criar um componente para avaliação, onde é possível avaliar algo com 0-5 estrelas clicando nos ícones das estrelas.
Mas da maneira que faço, estou excedendo a quantidade de `this.setState()` aninhados, o que gera erro pois pode causar um loop infinito.

**Código do Componente:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import { Container } from './styles';

class StarsToRate extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    const {
      size,
    } = this.props;
    this.state = {
      rating: 0,
      iconSize: size,
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { rating, iconSize } = this.state;
    return (
      <Container>
        {[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map((element) => {
          if (element <= rating) {
            return <Icon name="star" size={iconSize} color="#EBC600" onPress={this.setState({ rating: element })} />;
          }
          return <Icon name="star-border" size={iconSize} color="#EBC600" onPress={this.setState({ rating: element })} />;
        })}
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

StarsToRate.defaultProps = {
  size: 24,
};

StarsToRate.propTypes = {
  size: PropTypes.number,
};

export default StarsToRate;
```

**Erro exibido:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O problema não é que tu tá chamando o `setState` sempre? Tenta alterar o `onPress` para: `onPress={element => this.setState({rating: element})}`

Comment: `element` utilizado na _arrow function_  já está declarado no escopo superior, ao utilizar dessa maneira acusa-se um erro. Tentei contornar chamando uma outra função `touchStar(data) {
    this.setState({ rating: data });
  }`, mas volto ao erro de setState's aninhados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que você está chamando a função logo que você cria o componente. Tente substituir nos componentes o:

```
onPress={this.setState({ rating: element })}
```

por:

```
onPress={() => this.setState({ rating: element })}
```

[Exemplo funcional com botões](https://repl.it/repls/TwinJubilantRobodoc)

Comment: Funcionou muito bem, obrigado!